# Computer randomly shutting down

Tags: windows-7, crash, viewer, events

Well guys, whenever i play a game my computer will crash after a random amount of time, it doesnt appear to shut down if i leave it idle, it started off 2 months ago, and is starting to happen more frequently, my cpu usage is fine, my pc is not over restraining itself since im only running one game and a video on youtube to listen to while i play, when it does shut down, my monitor will close first saying there is no signal, the sound will play for another second and then keep playing that exact note it did before it closed, looping around until i start it again, i checked event viewer and i see few critical errors and warnings, ill post them here

Error 5/4/2014 5:34:51 AM EventLog 6008 None The previous system shutdown at 5:33:10 AM on ‎5/‎4/‎2014 was unexpected.

Critical 5/4/2014 5:34:44 AM Kernel-Power 41 (63) The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

Error 5/4/2014 5:34:53 AM Eventlog 1101 Event processing Audit events have been dropped by the transport. 0

Error 5/4/2014 5:36:35 AM WMI 10 None Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.

I am running windows 7, thank you

Comment: Have you tried swapping out the power supply? That sounds like a failing power supply.

Answer (score 0):

That is symptom of CPU overheating. Check for lint in the air intakes or inside the box, check if the fans are OK. The heat paste in the CPU might be old/dry, but that is less likely.